# Best Practice for choosing hyperparameters for stacking/majority voting

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, cross-validation, random-forest, boosting

My goal is to get the best hyperparameters for the classifiers I used in Stacking/Majority Voting.

This is the steps that I did (with very small Titanic dataset):

1. I use GridSearchCV to tune each classifiers (logreg, Random Forest, XGB, etc)
2. I use the best performing classifier, with the best hyperparameters from step 1. I always use `logreg` as the 2nd classifier when Stacking

My questions are :

1. Is it considered "best practice" to use the best hyperparameter of each classifier for Stacking/Majority Voting?
2. I found out that its possible to do GridSearchCV  when Stacking (with `mlxtend`), so the chosen hyperparameters is the best for Stacking, not the best for each classifier (as opposed to the 1st point). However, is it worthed the effort? I believed the computational cost will be huge because there will be a lot of hyperparameters combination for `GridSearchCV` to try.
3. Or do I missing something important here? Please kindly give me your practical advice

My current Stacking yields the best result, but only differ +- 1% from standalone advanced classifier (Random Forest/XGBoost)

Comment: I would say that your question is similar to portfolio management. You could fit a trading model for each asset separately. Alternatively you can use all available assets and tune their weights so that a measure of interest maximizes. You can very probably get different results of your measure of interest after the first and second approaches. Of course when you tune the parameters for the stack of models together, you have higher chances to get better results on train and validation, but not necessarily on test test due to the multiple selection bias (lots of combinations of param values).

Comment: Besides, you cannot expect better results whatever way of doing parameter search you prefer if your standalone classifiers produce 'intercorrelated' results, i.e., RF predictions correlate with GBM, or linear model predictions correlate with SVM.

Comment: So, my recimmendation of the best practice in this task is avoiding tuning multiple model hyperparameters at the same time as you become vulnerable to SEVERE chances of creating an overfit model.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @AlexeyBurnakov, could you explain more about " 
`Besides, you cannot expect better results whatever way of doing parameter search you prefer if your standalone classifiers produce 'intercorrelated' results`"?

Comment: And I don't get why tuning multiple model hyperparameters at the same time will lead to overfiting? I thought `GridSearchCV` will try each combination to get the best cross validation result? Or do you mean something like my model will "know to much" of the data because the training iterations from `GridSearchCV`?

Comment: First. A short answer: best results are obtained using independent predictions of appriximately equal quality, the ones which are orthogonal. An opposite case is using preeictors which 100% correlate. The you get no additional information at all. Let me write later a better Answer with theory references.

Comment: Second, short answer: the total number of combinations will grow as an exponential function. Given millions of param combinations you face a higher chance of utilizing multiple model selection bias in presence of millions or billions of models.

Comment: I added detailed answer to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a more specific answer:

> could you explain more about "   Besides, you cannot expect better
>   results whatever way of doing parameter search you prefer if your
>   standalone classifiers produce 'intercorrelated' results"?

The best results are obtained using independent predictions of appriximately equal quality, the ones which are orthogonal. An opposite case is using predictors which 100% correlate with other models' predictions. Then you get no additional information at all: all predictions tell you the same thing.

Imagine you apply a not perfect ruler to get estimates of your desired quality.

- Each measurement is independent of each other.
- The ruler application produces a random error each time.

Here assumptions allow the Law of Large Numbers (LLN) to come into effect. If you average many independent noisy measurements many times (limit is infinity) you will obtain a measurement infinitely close to the real value (on population).

Consider now a situation with correlated outputs from your models (one model application to one observation is one application of a ruler). I mean your models produce correlated outputs per observation in your sample with regard to other models' predictions for the same observations.

Since they are not independent, but indeed correlated, the LLN does not correctly apply here since the main assumption is broken. Hence you cannot expect to get an unbiased estimate even if you try lots of different models.

> And I don't get why tuning multiple model hyperparameters at the same
>   time will lead to overfiting?

Suppose you have 100 reasonable combinations of parameters per model (like, regularization coefficient, interaction depth, boosting iterations). If you feat 3 models separately, you parse through 300 possibilities. If instead of evaluating each model separately you decide to optimize the parameters for all models at once, you get 100 to the power of **n** model number. It can be 1 000 000 different model combinations if you have just 3 models... You really just create more hypotheses to check, each hypothesis is whether my model superposition is a good estimator of the modeled data.

The more the number of models to choose from the higher the chances that on train and validation you will get at least 1 model superposition which will show good estimates everywhere but on test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the concept. Do you mean linear regression and linear SVM are correlated (both of them are linear) hence I shouldn't combine them? What about logreg and rbf SVM?

Comment: Build one correlation matrix including the predictions from your models. You can attach it to your question and I guess it would be easier to see what you have. It is not necessary that linear models will correlate, but that could be the case with a better chance then for linear model VS decision tree.